# graph api for search is not functioning if the search pattern is a single word

Tags: facebook-graph-api

The graph api for search is not functioning if the search pattern is a single word.It gives empty result.
eg: 
    https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=mark&type=user

If you use two word query like below, you will get the result.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=ho hie&type=user
```

Even if it is URL encoded, like "ho%20%hie", the result will be empty.

Can anybody please help me out for finding the reason